# Iterate through table with li elements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Could someone please assist in following issue:
I have a table of dynamic data(s) and every row has 5 elements in it (there are 30 rows). I have to iterate through each of rows, pickup data of every column and check if it is not a zero.
Here is how it looks on page (actually it is picked up from xpath):

```
/html/body/main/article/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/ol[1]/li[3]/div[1]/a
```

Above is first user with its username.
All usernames (from that table) I see:

```
/html/body/main/article/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/ol[1]/li/div[1]/a
```

As you can see last **li** has not a number, and when it has, it points to a username on position: 1, 2, 3 .... 30
So, my question is, how can I use inside that **li** element iteration. I tried this:

```
First found size of table:
int all = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/main/article/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/ol[1]/li/div[1]/a")).size();
    for (int i = 0; i < all; i++) {
    //check if username exists and convert int to a string
    String j = Integer.valueOf(i);
```

And finally put that into found xpath element (last li):

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/main/article/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/ol[1]/li["+get(j)+"]/div[1]/a"))
```

What am I doing wrong and not getting changed **li[current number]** in every iteration?
Thank you in advance
[image]

Here is HTML:

```
<li class="list-item row">
<div class="column large-4 compete-standings-user">
 <div class="user-photo"><img 
 <a "profile/kalaka" title="Kalaka">Kalaka</a>
 <div class="column large-2 small-3 compete-standings-data">
 <strong>71</strong>blogs</div>
 <div class="column large-2 small-3 compete-standings-data">
 <strong>+69.9</strong>Accepted</div>
 <div class="column large-2 small-3 compete-standings-data">
 <strong>+21.1%</strong>Pending</div>
 <div class="column large-2 small-3 compete-standings-datae">
 <strong>L100</strong>Earned</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you link the page?

Comment: @JeffC unfortunately not, since it is in develop stage, and not public

Comment: @JeffC If can help added screenshot in question. Note that there are 6th and 7th in the list (users) and I have to pickup (in one iteration) its username, check if number of blogs exist, number of pending exists, how much earned and after that go to 7th user (next one) and so on.

Comment: Please post the HTML for an entire row, e.g. 6 Kalaka from your screenshot.

Comment: @JeffC Added HTML and screenshot how it looksl like in Dev Tool (marked is that user which is 6th li in the list

Comment: What does a failed case look like? You stated make sure they aren't zero. Is zero in Accepted or pending literally "0" or "+0.0" or "0.0" or "-0.0"? What about Earned? Will it be "£0" or "0" as the fail case?

Comment: @JeffC Did not specify (sorry for that), and here is:
- blog & earn are Integers
- Accepted & Pending are float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the quick way to get the text that you want to check is to use the CSS selector, `ol.compete-standings > strong`. If you notice the HTML, each of the numbers that you want to check are in a `STRONG` tag. This locator gets all the `STRONG` tags inside the outer `OL` tag.

```
List<WebElement> numbers = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("ol.compete-standings > strong"));
for (WebElement number : numbers)
{
    String s = number.getText().replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
    Assert.assertNotEquals(0, Integer.parseInt(s));
}
```

This code strips out all characters except for numbers, converts the string to an `int`, and asserts (using TestNG) that the number is not zero. If you aren't using `TestNG` (or the equivalent)... you should be :). You can just sub in your own validation.

Comment: Understood, but how can I iterate for a next user in a list. I was hoping when (i.e finish checking 6th user, I mean all of his data) to go to next with **for loop** and check 7th user (if he/she has all data starting with username).  That is what I wrote in question: _And finally put that into found xpath element (last li):_ (and code below).

Comment: This checks ALL users.

Comment: Understood. Thank you for your effort

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an example of how it might be done using regex.

Comment: Thank you one more time. Just saw it.